# How get current timezone?

Tags: magento, timezone

For me to have magento bug in timezone, because some places it uses the timezone selected in administration, and in other areas it The use UTC.

I want to know how to take the timezone that is selected in the administration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone')
```